# How do I left or right align text in Google Chrome 6 address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I was typing into Google Chrome's address bar and I think I hit some keys by accident that right aligned the text in the bar. This is very annoying! What might I have pressed? How can I change this back?

[image]

Comment: More like, how do you align text to the right?! :p

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[Looks like it relates to Right To Left language support.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=418c73eb0568ffca&hl=en)  Try hitting:

<kbd>LeftShift</kbd>+<kbd>LeftControl</kbd>

at the same time to see if it resolves.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: its too late but its LeftControl + LeftShift .

Comment: you can use any 'ctrl' but press 'shift' according to cursor position you need like for right press right shift otherwise press left shift.keep it more simple :D

Comment: Did not work on firefox on ubuntu.

Comment: This works on all input boxes on Windows

Answer (score 13):

If you want to align to left then simply hold "CTRL" and then press "LEFT SHIFT"

If you want to align to right then simply hold "CTRL" and the press "RIGHT SHIFT".

Answer (score 6):

Okay, none of the above worked for me and i think i found a solution which works well on my Chrome for Windows 10. Holding Ctrl and then pressing the right Shift button moves the text in address bar to right. Holding Ctrl and then pressing the left Shift button moves it back to the left. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Kudos for solving this.  However, this is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>LeftControl</kbd> + <kbd>LeftShift</kbd> align addressbar text to left.

<kbd>RightControl</kbd> + <kbd>RightShift</kbd> align addressbar text to right.

Comment: Extremely confusing & questionable UX...

Answer (score 1):

I've done this so many times to myself you'd think I'd know it by heart... but I don't. I don't even have access to a Windows machine right now to give more exact details. But essentially, you should be able to right-click the address box and somewhere in the context menu there should be right-to-left and left-to-right alignment options...

As for what keys were pressed to do that? I don't know. I've yet to figure that one out myself.

Comment: ...There's no context options for this in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Chrome on a Mac, the only way I found how to change text alignment (when typing) is to right click on the text box - 'writing direction' - RTL\LTR.

to view a page in a different alignment I use this extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switch-direction/fldkjfjmcadcklboajlnclnfjpdopcce

if someone can tell how to change text alignment using a shortcut key that will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Point your mouse cursor to Address Bar and Press together with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome

Comment: Worked for me but for Firefox, not Chrome. Google brought me here when I searched without specifying the browser and I didn't notice.